# How to update only 1 of 2 params for a button-click but sending information to backend for both?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby, crud, fetch-api

I've got a React front-end and Sinatra/Ruby backend: I have a like button and a dislike button on my front-end, which (when clicked) update the backend via PATCH. These buttons are for a review that a user leaves which others can `like` or `dislike`, and that count is displayed live.

At the moment each button has a separate function but they're both extremely similar and I need to DRY them out but not sure how.

On the backend, here's the `review` object and what's being patched in:

```
     ## update the likes and/or dislikes count for the review
  patch "/reviews/:id" do
    review = Review.find(params[:id])
    review.update(
      likes: params[:likes],
      dislikes: params[:dislikes],
    )
    review.to_json
  end
```

The issue is that I can update the `likes` and `dislikes` successfully but when the page is reloaded, it will only display the actions of which button was click recently. For example, if a review has 0 `likes` and 0 `dislikes` to start, I can click 5 `dislikes` then 5 `likes` --> my reloading of the page will then only show 5 `likes` and 0 `dislikes`, as `likes` were the most recent button click.

The two button functions are here:

```
     // updates the likes per click on LIKE button
  function updateReviewLikes(eachReview) {
    fetch(
      `https://best-music-reviews-backend.herokuapp.com/reviews/${eachReview.id}`,
      {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          likes: eachReview.likes + 1,
        }),
      }
    )
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((reviewInfo) => {
        const updatedReviews = reviews.map((singleReview) => {
          if (parseInt(singleReview.id) === parseInt(reviewInfo.id)) {
            return { ...singleReview, likes: reviewInfo.likes };
          }
          return singleReview;
        });
        setReviews(updatedReviews);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }

  // updates the dislikes per click on DISLIKE button
  function updateReviewDislikes(eachReview) {
    fetch(
      `https://best-music-reviews-backend.herokuapp.com/reviews/${eachReview.id}`,
      {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          dislikes: eachReview.dislikes + 1,
        }),
      }
    )
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((reviewInfo) => {
        const updatedReviews = reviews.map((singleReview) => {
          if (parseInt(singleReview.id) === parseInt(reviewInfo.id)) {
            return { ...singleReview, dislikes: reviewInfo.dislikes };
          }
          return singleReview;
        });
        setReviews(updatedReviews);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }
```

I know conceptually this is what I'd like to have happen but ran into issues in the JSON.stringify as (I believe) the variable replacement isn't happening there. I still have to give it a shot using `${likeType}` string-literal syntax but this is what I'm working with.

```
   //* my conceptual attempt at DRYing the function
//* on each button click, likeType either = 'likes' or = 'dislikes'
let likeType = 'none';
function updateReview(eachReview, likeType) {
  console.log('likeType: ', likeType);
  fetch(
    `https://best-music-reviews-backend.herokuapp.com/reviews/${eachReview.id}`,
    {
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        likeType: eachReview.likeType + 1,
      }),
    }
  )
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((reviewInfo) => {=
      const updatedReview = reviews.map((singleReview) => {
        if (parseInt(singleReview.id) === parseInt(reviewInfo.id)) {
          return { ...singleReview, likeType: reviewInfo.likeType };
        }
        return singleReview;
      });
      setReviews(updatedReview);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

Everything works well otherwise and I'm pretty sure my error is in 1 of 2 areas here: within the JSON.stringify{} and/or on the 2nd .then where I'm working with the returned object once the PATCH has been successful.

Will take any steps in the right direction, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have multiple options to fix that:

1. Create seperate actions for `like` an `dislike`
2. Would be to fallback to review `like` or `dislike` if your params a not filled:

```rb
  ## update the likes and/or dislikes count for the review
  patch "/reviews/:id" do
    review = Review.find(params[:id])
    review.update(
      likes: params[:likes] || review.likes,
      dislikes: params[:dislikes] || review.dislikes,
    )
    review.to_json
  end
```

Or something like this, to avoid to update a column where you have an empty param. Simply reject it:

```rb
  ## update the likes and/or dislikes count for the review
  patch "/reviews/:id" do
    review = Review.find(params[:id])
    review_params = { likes: params[:likes], dislikes: params[:dislikes] }.reject { |_,v| v.blank? }
    review.update(review_params)
    review.to_json
  end
```

There are further more ways to solve it. Me for myself i would prefer solution one.

Comment: thank you! I will work this out when I reach my desk. I do like the succinct nature of the 1st approach with the OR condition.